# Where is ignorance, and why does it not end with death?

Tags: pratityasamutpada, death, ignorance, worldly

Where is ignorance, and why does it not end with death? Can we experience it? Does it have to be actively conditioning formations for us to experience it, or can we know this nidana even when freed from it?

I'm interested in an answer from any tradition.

Comment: it's a "cause", i guess. do causes exist both inside and outside their effects?

Comment: Hi sorta_buddhist, I have seen some of your questions on this site and they seem generally oriented towards emptiness questions, but with a lot of western philosophical notions spliced in and without a lot of detail as to where you are getting your questions/notions/definitions from. I've been trying to think how to answer or help you in whatever you are looking for, but it is difficult when the notions and jargon are imprecise or unclear. Take this question: you seem to be asking where (as in physical coordinates) 'ignorance' is, but I don't understand this... are you looking for x,y,z coord?

Comment: yeah, i was asking if it had a location.

Comment: Buddha said we should investigate for ourselves and seek out such answers. Where is your ignorance? Does it have a location or not? Whatever answer you come up with... why would it be different for others?

Comment: that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is ignorance, and why does it not end with death?

Ignorance is absence of right view. It's not tangible, as much as it is a lacking.

The buddhist notion of rebirth says that we're destined to samsara until sotapatti/"stream-entry" occurs to break the cycle.

> Can we experience it?

The most tangible evidence of avijja/ignorance is dukkha/suffering.

> Does it have to be actively conditioning formations for us to experience it, or can we know this nidana even when freed from it?

Regarding the first half of your question, ignorance is most likely conditioning formations in both a passive/and an active sense: Sometimes we end up in trouble without seeing it coming, and sometimes we end up in trouble because we deliberately ignore the consequences we have coming to us. These are two examples of how avijja may affect us.

Can't answer the last part of your question though. Sorry.

Comment: fair enough, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Ignorance includes self-view. Similarly, "death", being the idea "a being" or "a person" dies, is also a self-view. Since "death" is a self-view, the idea/mental construct of "death" cannot end ignorance.

When there is no self-view, there is no ignorance and there is also no idea of "death", as follows:

> Bhikkhu, ‘I am’ is a conceiving; ‘I am this’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall
>   be’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall not be’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be
>   possessed of form’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be formless’ is a
>   conceiving; ‘I shall be percipient’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be
>   non-percipient’ is a conceiving; ‘I shall be
>   neither-percipient-nor-non-percipient’ is a conceiving. Conceiving is
>   a disease, conceiving is a tumour, conceiving is a dart. **By overcoming
>   all conceivings**, bhikkhu, one is called **a sage at peace**. And the sage
>   at peace is not born, does not age, **does not die**....
>
> https://suttacentral.net/mn140/en/bodhi

Therefore, the '*Deathless*' can end ignorance but '*death*' cannot end ignorance.

Comment: i'm not sure i completely agree, but it's worth stating

Comment: i don't expect you to agree, based on the speculative nature of your question.

Comment: i mean "no idea of death", fwiw, not the rest of it

Comment: its all the same. you criticized me once for rejecting your "mind only" ideas and now you criticize me when i say "death" is a mind only phenomena

Comment: i'm not sure we disagree